# Is Solr 5.1 Master and Slave configuration will work in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr

I am new for AWS and Solr. I am working to setup solr in AWS for my Sitecore 8.2 instance. When I searched for the solr setup, I found two types of the config setups. 1) Master slave configuration 2)SolrCloud.

I just want to know is Master slave configuration will work well in AWS/any limitation there in this configuration? or SolrCloud only work in AWS?

Please suggest if you already come across this?

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: its better to go for SolrCLoud...

Comment: As long as you have private connectivity between nodes, both will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit and MatsLindh for your valuable input